# How to get all categories and subcategories names from mysql using php

Tags: php

I Have a table `categories` like so

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id int not null primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    main_name varchar(64)
    sub_name varchar(64)
)
```

Now I want to get all categories and subcategories to fetch the side bar:

```
<?php
    $query = "SET names 'utf8'";
    $send_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $query = "SELECT main_name FROM categories";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    $array = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ( !in_array($row['main_name'], $array)) {

            echo "<a href='' class='list-group-item'>{$row['main_name']}</a>";
            array_push($array, $row['main_name']);

            $query = "SELECT sub_name FROM categories WHERE main_name=".$row['main_name'];
            $inner_query_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            if($inner_query_result !== FALSE) { 
                while ($inner_row = mysqli_fetch_array($inner_query_result)) {
                    echo $inner_row['sub_name'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

But i'm getting no subcategories, because second query is failing, don't know why. How to get all subcategories correctly?

Comment: add `mysqli_error($connection)` to every query; what does it show? The errors are obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

ah, I'm get it, missed quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT sub_name FROM categories WHERE main_name='".$row['main_name']."'";
```